# ArgoCD syncPolicy automated prune true, selfheal true delete helm app doesn't delete helm app resources

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, argocd

I have simple test ArgoCD `app of apps` which references a git repo with a folder. In that folder I have a single file with the Helm application. When I deployed `app of apps` it created additional application for the helm chart. There was an issue as I have not provided a helm argument as result it attempted to bind newly created PVC to already bound PV. It failed to do that. I have decided to try again. I have deleted `app of apps`, as result it deleted automatically helm app, but resources of the helm app are still there. They were not removed.
Both apps have

```yaml
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfheal: true
```

I wonder why the resources of the helm chart has not been deleted? I would like them go away so that I don't need to go and remove them manually. I could do this if there was a helm release deployed but `helm list` returns nothing. Is there a reason why argocd helm  doesn't crea

Comment: How did you delete the app of apps? Inside ArgoCD UI or using kubectl? I dont think you did a cascade-delete in UI, right?
Have a look at adding the deletion-finalizer to your Argo application resource:
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/app_deletion/#about-the-deletion-finalizer

Answer (score 1):

in order to automatically delete child resources in app-of-apps pattern, you have to add finalizer to the application.yaml of the child module in metadata section

```
finalizers:
 - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
```